# Writing to a file with NTFS compression takes more time than writing to an uncompressed file

Tags: c#, compression, ntfs

It is described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b63b4a4-b197-4286-8f3f-af2498e3afe5/ntfs-compression-in-c?forum=netfxbcl) how to compress a file, but once that file already exists.

I adapted it a little bit, so I am now trying to create a file with the NTFS compression attribute set on the file as soon as the file stream is created and then adding data to the file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Compress {
    class Program {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int DeviceIoControl(IntPtr hDevice, int
        dwIoControlCode, ref short lpInBuffer, int nInBufferSize, IntPtr
        lpOutBuffer, int nOutBufferSize, ref int lpBytesReturned, IntPtr
        lpOverlapped);
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        string fileName = @"D:\temp\t.txt";
        int lpBytesReturned = 0;
        int FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION = 0x9C040;
        short COMPRESSION_FORMAT_DEFAULT = 1;

        byte[] data = new byte[4096];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
            data[i] = 42;
        }

        Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        FileStream f = File.Open(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
            System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, System.IO.FileShare.None);

        int result = DeviceIoControl(f.Handle, FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION,
            ref COMPRESSION_FORMAT_DEFAULT, 2 /*sizeof(short)*/, IntPtr.Zero, 0,
            ref lpBytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero);


        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            f.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        f.Close();

        timer.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Time to write file = " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I am writing around 4KB of data each time. On my system this takes around 650 ms. If I remove the DeviceIoControl function call and run the same test, then it is a little bit faster and runs in around 550 ms (on the average over several runs).

I would expect that compressing would create lesser amount of data to store, as per [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2008/05/20/understanding-ntfs-compression.aspx).

> NTFS compresses files by dividing the data stream into CU’s (this is similar to how sparse files work).  When the stream contents are created or changed, each CU in the data stream is compressed individually.  If the compression results in a reduction by one or more clusters, the compressed unit will be written to disk in its compressed format.

Couple of questions:

What could explain the increase in time when I store the data via NTFS compression? I do not notice a substantial change in CPU usage (via task manager) between the 2 test runs (the CPU was stable at 5% in both the cases)

The amount of compression is also quite small, the file size was 390MB but the size on disk reduced to only 259MB. considering that the data is completely redundant, why is the amount of compression so low?

Comment: I would have been surprised of the opposite

Comment: The data compression is accomplished by an algorithm that the data is run through before commiting to disk. This algorithm (which is not required on a non-compressed file) takes a small bit of time to run. Hence the increased write time for a compressed file. You should find that reading from a compressed file will also take a bit more time than reading from a non-compressed file for the same reason.

Comment: 2nd question - The amount of compression you will achieve for any given piece of data will vary depending on the type of data being compressed. In general, the more repetitive the data, the greater the compression that is possible. Another possibility is that, due to the small amount of data you are compression, the symbol tree in the compressed data may be artificially inflating the size. With most compression schemes, there is a point of diminishing returns for how much data you are trying to compress, the more the better.

Comment: How are you getting the 390Mb/259Mb number?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what exactly you're doing, but it sounds like you are appending to an existing compressed file, 4K at a time.  The bottom line is that you can't expect much compression if you are only giving the compressor 4K to work with.  Compression depends on history and statistics to compress, and needs much more than that to take advantage of, for example, repeated strings and biased frequency distributions.

If you wrote the entire file at once, you would likely see much more effective compression.

Answer (score 0):

I think your test is a little messed up - if you want repeatable results, use FileMode.Create and let it rebuild the file each time.  As it stands, you're adding to the file on each run.  Who knows how many runs worth of data you have in there :-)  FileMode.Create will create the file, or truncate it if it exists.  I bet your compression ratio will look a little more reasonable after you've fixed that.

The overhead of compression takes time - even if the data is very smooth.  Your numbers look reasonable to me - the CPU never appears to be tasked, because it's doing the "hard work" of compression only once per *synchronous* I/O request - so the CPU added overhead won't tip the meter much at all - since it is spread-out in a mostly-I/O job.

Also - NTFS compression results in pretty badly fragmented files - this is especially true of large files - and isn't recommended.  You end up with a sparse-like file, too...one that will report more space consumed than is actually used to store the file.  The OS can use the sparse-like clusters for other files - but the size reporting is messed up.  Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) wikipedia article (under the heading File compression).

Comment: And, given that the program is doing cached I/O, there's almost no disk I/O at all. The writes are aggregated into RAM and then when the lazy writer starts flushing (asynchronous to your application) the cpu consumption will go up.

Comment: Also, even though there is a CPU hit, quite often it is easily tolerated because of the reduced amount of data that is being read/written.